# How To Override Standard Edit Button In Salesforce Case Detail Page and Call A Custom Lighting Component

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have a case in which i want to override  standard Edit Button Call A Custom Lignting Component on Record Detail Page

How do i do that?

[image]

Your help is highly appreciated

Regards,
Carolyn